# C# Save selected items in bootstrap listbox to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm trying to find out how to save checked list elements from the listbox to a database. I know, if I use asp-Listbox-element its quite easy and I know how it works, but I can't add this bootstrap listbox style to it, so I have to work with the standard one.

Here's my listbox code:

```
<div class="form-group" runat="server">   
                            <select multiple class="form-control" id="wnd_area_listbox">
                              <option value="trocken">trocken</option>
                              <option value="schuppig">schuppig</option>
                              <option value="feucht">feucht</option>
                              <option value="rissig">rissig</option>
                              <option value="mazeriert">mazeriert</option>
                              <option value="haarlos">haarlos</option>
                              <option value="odematös">odematös</option>
                              <option value="überwämt">überwärmt</option>
                              <option value="ekzeme">Ekzeme</option>
                              <option value="gerötet">gerötet</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
```

If it was an asp-listbox i could easily call it from codeBehind with the id and iterate through the selected values, but i dont know how to do it with "normal" HTML/Bootstrap-List.

Would be great to get some ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### use asp.net control

one way is to use an asp.net control - the ListBox with multiple selection mode

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:ListBox ID="" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" 
        SelectionMode="Multiple" >
         <asp:ListItem Text="trocken" Value="trocken"></asp:ListItem>
         .... rest of list.....
     </asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

### second way - html asp.net control

One other way is to read the post back of this control on code behind - put `runat="server"` on the html control

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="wnd_area_listbox" runat="server" >
```

and read the value as

```
Request.Form[wnd_area_listbox.UniqueID]
```

### with simple html control

Other way is to place the `name` on your html control and read it on post back

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="wnd_area_listbox" name="wnd_area_listbox" >
```

and read the value as

```
Request.Form["wnd_area_listbox"]
```